# SQL Server Partitioning - Notion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-partitioning

I have got a database consisting of about several thousand of tables (from 2005) where about 20-30% of them have incremental rowcount of about 200k/yr.

The requirement is to visualize the statistics of the table based on the column `lastAccessedDate`. The scheme is to classify into parition groups `(10 y, 5y, 3y, 1y, 6m, 3m, 1m, 2w, currentDate)`. Say the partitions are named `p1,p2,..p10`

I am able to understand that multiple partitionining groups can be defined to the tables [link](http://sqlandme.com/2011/07/22/sql-server-horizontally-partitioning-a-sql-server-database-table/).

The job runs every week and therefore, the partitioning scheme varies on the current date; i.e. After a week, the `p10` becomes `p9`. After two weeks, `p9` becomes `p8` and after a month, `p8` becomes `p7`; I hope you get the idea.

1. Is the partitioning scheme based on the current date feasible?
2. If this is feasible, is it worthwhile to horizontally partition the tables and query them instead of running the query through the entire table? The SQL Server reports suggests the total space usage is around 31,556 MB.

I am running this on a SQL Server 2008 instance.

Comment: why do you want to visualise the statistics? To decide on a partitioning scheme? What do you hope to achieve by partitioning? read performance improvement? write performance improvement? You need to design your partition for that purpose. If you don't read or write data based around the date partitions you mentioned, they really don't serve any purpose.

Comment: The current idea or requirement is like a MRU cache like system for a SQL database. Under this project instance, older data is least likely to be accessed. In order to make the read faster for queries that deal with the newer data, I have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You mention data storage and statistics requirements. These two should not be confused. Storage solutions are made for quick access of data, and statistics are in the domain of reporting and visualisation.

With respect to storage you should use partitioning, but not in the proposed way. You can have 10.000 partitions in SQL server, so you could use `one day` or `one week` as a usefull partition key. Once created you can switch sections in and out of the partitioned table, but you should not move the data from an existing partition to another partition, for this implies the recalculation all constraints and indexes. In views you can create additional values for later 'group by' actions. These groups can describe the required '1d, 1w, 1m, 1q, 1y' reporting values.

So yes it's feasible and recommended to use partitions for your case, but in a different way then proposed.

Comment: I get that this can be done using the SQL Group By clause but wouldn't the incremental nature of the entire table be detrimental to the query? If the data is newer, I can run the group by query but in case of older data the query runs really slow. This is one of the primary reasons to partition the data and to make query faster.

Comment: If this is a performance tuning exercise, don't just jump straight to partitioning. Have you confirmed that you've run out of options for indexes?